# Does Infinity War have the most credited people ever (so far)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, production

Having just seen *Avengers: Infinity War*, and, of course, waiting around until after the credits for the inevitable post-credits scene, it's quite noticeable that an immense number of people worked on this film.   (In fact, people around me in the theatre were commenting to this effect.)

Now, this isn't really surprising given:

- The immense cast overall
- The immense number of A-list cast, who come with their own assistants of various types
- The shear scale and number of the fighting scenes, which require stunt personnel, extras, etc
- The huge running time of CGI effects, as well as the diversity of *different* effects which all require separate models, animation, etc.
- The large number of real world shooting sites, which all require separate logistics, food service, etc.

**So, is this in fact the movie with the largest number of named individuals in the credits to date?**

Comment: The only other movie(s) I can think of off hand that might match or beat it would be one or more of the Lord of the Rings films. But I couldn't say for sure if they do.

Comment: @Xantec:   Yeah, I thought of that, but it doesn't feel likely because of the smaller cast and fewer shooting locations.

Comment: Someone with programming and database chops may be able to use the IMDB API and find out relatively easily.

Comment: Didn't LOTR credit/acknowledge a couple of thousand Tolkein fans or something?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-movie-had-the-most-number-of-people-listed-in-the-closing-credits/amp

Comment: I wasn't exactly considering the fan club.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yup the entire roll of the official Tolkien Fan Club, that alone takes nearly five minutes of the end credits. They also credit all the extras by name for every movie including those for the battles of Helm's Deep in Two Towers and the Pelennor Fields in Return of the King.

Comment: Since this Tolkien Fan Club thing seems to be a bit of a special case, it seems like the answer should probably talk about the number of credited people who actually contributed to the film vs. who just appeared in the credits.   And for the purpose of that last sentence I'm not accepting that "being a supporter via the Fan Club" actually counts as "contributing".

Comment: Some projects backed by Kickstarter have hundreds, if not thousands, of backers listed in their credits.

Comment: @thepopmachine if you look on IMDB the lord of the rings trilogy has a surprisingly small number for cast and crew in comparison to other si ilair films. Part of the reason for this is the length of time taken to film and all 3 movies being filmed simultaneously this allowed a far better use of resources

Answer (score 7):

IMDB lists the full cast and crew at 3296 https://m.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/fullcredits

Ironman 3 had 3846 
https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1300854/fullcredits

So no it isn’t and there may be other films that beat Ironman 3 given it is now several years old.

Comment: Tallying up all the numbers on that list for Iron Man 3 I get *3,846*, and for Infinity War *3,296*. Are there certain categories you're leaving out, or is this just summation errors?

Comment: my mistake I was adding up on my phone and looking at the same time, have updated the numbers, but it still makes the point Iron man had more :)

Comment: Is that source accurate?

Comment: IMDB is considered an industry point of reference within the film, cinema and TV industry therefore it is as accurate as you can get without counting the credits yourself.